# Using thrust::max_element in a CUDA C project

Tags: cuda, max, thrust

In a CUDA C project, I would like to try and use the Thrust library in order to find the maximum element inside an array of floats. It seems like the Thrust function thrust::max_element() is what I need. The array on which I want to use this function is the result of a cuda kernel (which seems to work fine) and so it is already present in device memory when calling thrust::max_element().
I am not very familiar with the Thrust library but after looking at the documentation for thrust::max_element() and reading the answers to similar questions on this site, I thought I had grasped the working principles of this process. Unfortunately I get wrong results and it seems that I am not using the library functions correctly. Can somebody please tell me what is wrong in my code?

```
float* deviceArray;
float* max;
int length = 1025;

*max = 0.0f;
size = (int) length*sizeof(float);     

cudaMalloc(&deviceArray, size);
cudaMemset(deviceArray, 0.0f, size);

// here I launch a cuda kernel which modifies deviceArray

thrust::device_ptr<float> d_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(deviceArray);
*max = *(thrust::max_element(d_ptr, d_ptr + length));
```

I use the following headers:

```
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
```

I keep getting zero values for *max even though I am sure that deviceArray contains non-zero values after running the kernel. 
I am using nvcc as a compiler (CUDA 7.0) and I am running the code on a device with compute capability 3.5.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is not proper C code:

```
float* max;
int length = 1025;

*max = 0.0f;
```

You're not allowed to store data using a pointer (`max`) until you properly provide an allocation for that pointer (and set the pointer equal to the address of that allocation).

Apart from that, the rest of your code seems to work for me:

```
$ cat t990.cu
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(){

  float* deviceArray;
  float max, test;
  int length = 1025;

  max = 0.0f;
  test = 2.5f;
  int size = (int) length*sizeof(float);

  cudaMalloc(&deviceArray, size);
  cudaMemset(deviceArray, 0.0f, size);
  cudaMemcpy(deviceArray, &test, sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  thrust::device_ptr<float> d_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(deviceArray);
  max = *(thrust::max_element(d_ptr, d_ptr + length));
  std::cout << max << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t990 t990.cu
$ ./t990
2.5
$
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, sorry for the incorrect C code in the variable declaration section, I wrote it without thinking too much. As you may have imagined, the code I reported here is part of a bigger script and the wrong part in the beginning is trying to synthesize something different, but I wanted to write something for completeness. Unfortunately I did it too much in a hurry. Anyways, thank you again for showing this working code to me: I must assume the bug is somewhere else, then.